# Why is GoogleBot not seeing my React Router anchor tags?

Tags: jsx, react-router-dom, googlebot

I am having issues with GoogleBot crawler not seeing my anchor tags for internal links (import Link as RouterLink from 'react-router-dom').  I am using a custom button and custom Link that takes to="" as a prop and RouterLink as component prop.  When I inspect the button/link it shows  but apparently the crawler isn't picking it up.  Here is what the button looks like...

```
            <VpButton
              className={homeStyles.aboutUsButton}
              id="homeAboutUsBtn"
              aria-label="About Us"
              variant="outlined"
              component={RouterLink}
              to="/aboutus"
            >
              ABOUT US
            </VpButton>
```

and here is the custom button

```
VpButtonProps<S = H.LocationState> extends ButtonProps {
  id: string;
  label?: string;
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  component?: React.ComponentType<any> | undefined;
  to?:
    | H.LocationDescriptor<S>
    | ((location: H.Location<S>) => H.LocationDescriptor<S>);
}

const VpButton = (props: VpButtonProps): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <Button
      classes={props.classes}
      {...props}
      onClick={(e) => {
        AwsAmplifyService.track('click', {
          elementId: props.id,
          type: 'button',
          label: props.label || props.children,
        });
        !!props.onClick && props.onClick(e);
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Button>
  );
};
```

like I said when I inspect the button, it is compiled as an anchor with the href='/aboutus' which is the same as the to='/aboutus' so anyone know why the crawler isn't picking this up?

Comment: What is `RouterLink`? Can you include all relevant code in your question?

Comment: RouterLink is Link from the react-router-dom...sorry it is imported as Link as RouterLink

Comment: So you mean `import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';`? Can you confirm/add this to your question?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: how do you know that googlebot is not crawling it?